# eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a vector twhen a multiple of identity matrix is added to the matrix?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

will the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a vector A change when a multiple of the identity matrix is added to it. for instancce (A + 3I)

Comment: What do you think? Let $A$ be the null matrix. What happens?

Comment: can't visualize what's going to happen. please explain

Answer (score 4):

the eigenvalue will change but not the eigenvector.  that is if $Au = \lambda u,$ then $(A + 3I)u=(\lambda + 3)u.$

in general if $p(\lambda)$ is a polynomial, then $p(A)$ ahs an eigenvalue $p(\lambda).$  for eaxmple, an eigenvalue of $A^2 + 2A + 3I$ is $\lambda^2 + 2\lambda + 3.$

Comment: @AliNaqvi, you are welcome. have fun with linear.